# AlaSql error while exporting XLS from HTML with style formatting

Tags: angularjs, xlsx, alasql

Alasql seems very helpful to export XLS files from JS and easy too.
But there is a lack of good tutorial or maybe I didn't find one.

During export XLS directly from HTML it works fine but I am not able to add some cell formatting in this process.

I tried this-

```
$scope.exportExcel = function() {
        // WORKS FINE
        /* alasql('SELECT * INTO XLSX("myinquires.xlsx", {headers:true}) \
                    FROM HTML("#MyInquires", {headers:true})');*/

       // produces error        
       alasql('SELECT * INTO XLSX("myinquires.xlsx", {headers:true,column:{width:300}}) \
                    FROM HTML("#MyInquires", {headers:true})');
}
```

The same styles worked fine while exporting from Object instead of HTML.

Both the code here-
http://plnkr.co/edit/bZsFYkaKIvN26XmpbqCy?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

I used below **code** to format my *Excel*, hope this will help,

```
    $scope.exportData = function () {
    var mystyle = {
        headers: true,            
        column: { style: { Font: { Bold: "1" } } },
        rows: { style: { Font: { Color: "#fff" } } },
        cells: {
            style: { Font: { Color: "#00FFFF" } }
        }
    };
    $scope.getFilteredColumnsForExcel = "Some Data";
    alasql('SELECT * INTO XLSXML("test.xls",?) FROM ?', [mystyle, $scope.getFilteredColumnsForExcel]);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I want to get it from HTML as my '$scope.getFilteredColumnsForExcel' object has unnecessary variables. Then I have to filter out those items before exporting XLS -which I don't want to.

Comment: +1, but I want to use from HTML as there are some parsing logic applied, which I need to again apply into the  '$scope.getFilteredColumnsForExcel'